# Any hidden disadvantage to lever-type door latches?

Tags: doorknob

I have a lever-type door knob on one of my bedrooms and I like it a lot more than the ordinary round knobs. I am considering replacing all the door knobs in the house with levers. Is there any reason to not do this? Why do people use round knobs at all?

Comment: Related question on User Experience: [Why do door knobs still exist?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/57929/14515)

Comment: I had a unpleasant accident with a lever handle few years ago: I was in a hurry trying to go through a door and got my wedding ring to be caught by the lever, then I pulled my hand away from the door causing the ring to bite into my finger deep enough to leave a scar and bend a ring so I was unable to remove it without tools.

Comment: Knobs are against code in Vancouver BC now.

Comment: Most of the doors in our house use levers, and the one difficulty of note is the tendency to snag.  Depending on your height, what you're wearing, what you're carrying, how you move through the door, etc, you could snag your belt loop, shirt or jacket sleeve, the handle of a bag you're carrying, etc.

Comment: My cat can open lever-doors, but not knobbed ones. That's a big deal to me :)

Comment: @nord so much this. I get WAY more stuff caught on levers than on knobs (although this is less of a problem now that I use wireless headphones :)

Comment: @Jim W Do you have a reference for that? I can see that they are more handicap-friendly than knobs, but to require them universally, per code seems like an extreme limitation, even here in BC.

Comment: The [Americans with Disabilities Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americans_with_Disabilities_Act_of_1990) requires levers in commercial buildings and elsewhere. Knobs are a major impediment to anyone with fine motor function challenges, loss of limbs, etc.

Comment: @mickeyf take your pick :) https://www.google.ca/search?q=vancouver+door+knobs+ban

Comment: It's much more difficult for velociraptors to open doors with knobs.

Comment: @Jim W Well, I'm glad I live on the island then. For commercial space, sure, but enforcing that for private residences? Clearly some city council member never got his or her clothing snagged or had any of the other accidents mentioned here due to one of those levers. Apparently in Kanata ON you're not allowed to paint your front door the color of your choice either. (Sorry, no reference.) This could all too easily migrate to politics.stackexchange ...;-) )

Comment: A photo would be extremely helpful.. I had no idea what anyone was talking about until I got to the SIXTH answer below.

Comment: Submarine doors offer an excellent compromise between the lever and rotary designs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In my experience, and in general terms...

Knobs are:

- Familiar (in the U.S)
- Low-profile (more compact horizontally)
- Funcional with ambidexterity/symmetry/bidirectionality (operate the same from any side--some levers only function downward)
- Non-snagging (and slightly more secure for this reason)
- Less expensive due to production cost and/or sales volume
- Better suited to some tastes and home styles

Levers are:

- Familiar (in Europe and elsewhere)
- Handicap-friendly (and, conversely, not as child-secure)
- More striking in appearance
- Swing-specific
- Likely to catch on straps and clothing on occasion
- Better suited to some tastes and home styles

<sub>Comment addition credit:
[Matt Lacey](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/58964/matt-lacey), [Angew](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/23104/angew), [Ferrybig](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/20590/ferrybig), [Accccumulation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/84414/acccumulation)</sub>

Comment: Levels are also more friendly to small children and certain pets!

Comment: We have them throughout the house. Some minor problems: Some dogs can unlatch doors with lever-type knobs. Bedroom and bathroom doors off a hall usually open inward so the lever is not an obstruction, but we put a lever on the outward opening door for the a/c air handler. It hangs out into the hall and it's an obstruction.

Comment: "Familiar" and possibly also "More striking in appearance" is culture-specific. In my part of the world (Czech Republic), you'd be hard-pressed to find a home with knob-style door handles in it.

Comment: Most door knobs I've seen stick further out from the door than most handles I've seen. I've snagged on a door handle twice in my life - I see other people snagged maybe once a year, it's really not a big concern. It's not like stairs made from ice or concrete, more like arguing for pine stairs over oak stairs becuase "you'll slip and die on the oak!!!"...

Comment: @Angew Same in the UK, doorknobs are rare, particularly in newer homes.

Comment: If I'm using my hands to carry something, I can't open knobbed doors with my elbow.

Comment: I don't think ambidexstrocity really applies.  If your 'off' hand can't push a lever, you have bigger problems :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft My thoughts exactly.  They do not take much force, you can basically just use your hands weight to open it.  You might have to rotate your torso slightly so your off hand can reach across; but that's the same for knobs.

Comment: I wouldn't say "not as child-secure" for a lever, which in case of a fire might make the difference between getting out or not, for a child. We went with levers thoughout the house when the first kid was born, so he could more easily move around.

Comment: I'm not going to follow this thread and scrutinize each point of my answer, but I'd be interested to hear a better word for "can be turned in either direction". I was describing the knob as ambidextrous, not the user.

Comment: I've had clever cats _and_ dogs figure out how to open a lever-handle before.  It's nearly impossible for them to open a knob.

Comment: My hips are exactly at doorknob height.  While going through partially open doors, I've ripped the belt loops off of several pair of slacks by catching them on those danged levers.  There are no longer any lever handles in my house.

Comment: @WayneConrad There are zounds of lever designs, thin, thick, straight, curved... I cannot imagine what you have to do to catch any clothes on a door lever in my office...

Comment: It seems to mean that the noun form of "ambidextrous" would be "ambidexterity". Other terms would be "symmetrical" and "bidirectional".

Comment: We had a dog who learned how to turn a doorknob to let himself into the house. It started with him scratching at the door; one day, he must have brushed a paw against the side of the knob in just the right way (it operated with little force, lightly sprung), and it opened. After some "trial and error", he eventually figured out how to get the door to open pretty reliably with little or no scratching. So, just because it's a knob and not a lever, don't assume it will be secure against a large, intelligent dog (a lab, in our case).

Answer (score 29):

It‘s interesting how these things differ among cultures!

In Europe (Germany for sure, but I never observed a difference in other European countries) basically all doors have levers. Here you install a knob only when you *need* the feature that it becomes more difficult open a door for pets and toddlers.

However, in most of these cases you can already get away with putting the handle upright, so knobs are really rare.

Comment: This. Knob vs. lever seems to be a cultural much more than a practical thing. For us Europeans, the door knobs so popular in America seem strange and odd.

Comment: I think it has mostly to do with what manufacturers were making 100 years ago. Most historical buildings in the US have knobs. Levers were rare, and are becoming more popular and common with time.

Comment: Europe/Germany: knobs are used here for outside doors (house, garden) where unlocking by key is the predominant use case. These knobs often don't turn at all, they are only for pulling/pushing.

Comment: As a personal anecdote, my building door in France has a knob rather than a lever or handle. Many deliverymen will not even try to open it, thinking you need the key to unlatch it.

Comment: @cbeleites I wouldn't call them knobs at all actually, they're more like handles...

Answer (score 10):

My wife and I moved into a home with lever door handles.  One big downside was our **young children**, who instantly knew how to open them and escape.  You can't childproof these easily either (they have devices, they just don't work as well).

Comment: Living in a part of the world where people don't use doorknobs, but levers exclusivly; it is common practice (and easy) to change the levers in a vertical position while children are young. They won't be able to open them.

Comment: In our house the doors came with useful devices called keys

Comment: Note that the keys mentioned by @PlasmaHH are only to protect against accidental door opening. You can buy one that opens all internal doors in all houses for cheap at the hardware store

Comment: Having doors that can be locked with keys and children in the same room might be dangerous. The small kid could lock him/her-self in the room alone if you leave the key in its hole.

Comment: Your not supposed to lock your kids in.

Comment: @MarkO, note that levers sold for the US market can't be easily changed to a vertical position.  Well, at least not the major brands that I've been in contact with.

Comment: @J.A.I.L. For a lock in a home like that,  they generally aren't overly secure locks.  I know most knob with locks also have a hole on the other side to disengage the lock by pressing into the hole.  The locks are really only for privacy.  I assume most lever handles have something similar.

Comment: @PlasmaHH you have key locks on all your inside doors??  Either way, are you going to carry around a ring of keys in your house and constantly lock/unlock doors, or just throw a few of these [door knob safety covers](http://a.co/9FxlcUu) on the door knobs where you don't want the kids to get through, but want easy access for yourself?

Comment: @sǝɯɐſ: yes, almost all houses/apartments around here do. We either store the keys in the doors (sufficient for cat safety) or if the kids should not reach them either on the doorframe (if wide enough) or on a small nail. Some people also hide them if necessary. We have lever type doorhandles here so that device would not work. Also it would be annoying to have to buy those for cat protection. Its nice that the standard door here basically comes with all you need.

Answer (score 6):

The one mayor **hidden** disadvantage is that they need a spring to keep the lever/handle in horizontal position.

I found after moving to a 20 years old house that some of them were not horizontal, but in a falling/diagonal position. They didn't latch the door, and don't look nice, as can be seen at the begining of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_y2_sCDnj4

Furthermore, the spring in the lever is not standard, and finding one that suits a handle that is not manufactured anymore is not an easy task. You can get more information on that in [this site](https://www.doorhandlesprings.co.uk/pages/choosing-the-correct-door-handle-spring).

Comment: I usually replace the whole assembly. most are riveted anyways so not really repair friendly. I am not much used to knobs but all I can remember turn back automatically so must have springs too

Comment: I can't replace the whole assembly: it's not manufactured anymore.

Comment: then get one that is compatible, I have never had a problem to find any, they have pretty standard measurements for most of their features.

Comment: Then I would end up with all the knobs in my house equal and one different.

Comment: no, I mean the part that goes inside the door, That one with the spring. Replace that, put on the old handles, done.

Comment: There are 2 springs: One in the latch inside the door (that part is standard and replaceable), and another spring in the lever-handle to keep it back to horizontal position. Edited my post to clarify this.

Comment: Then they work quite differently than the european style ones. They have an assembly with a square hole that you put whatever handle you like into. Inside the assembly is a spring that keeps the hole vertical

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75491/discussion-between-j-a-i-l-and-plasmahh).

Comment: All internal latch mechs have a return spring.  If they didn't, the round-knob types wouldn't self-latch when closed any more than the lever types.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft if you see the video, or check the link in my answer, you'll see that, beside the spring in the internal latch, levers have a spring. The spring in the internal latch is nos strong enough to keep the latch in horizontal position.

Answer (score 6):

To add another bullet point to supplement the other good answers: While most exterior doors are pretty close to air tight and security is generally not a concern for interior doors, locks on lever-type handles are typically easy to bypass if there is any sort of gap at the bottom of the door (typical of interior doors). This can be a benefit if you know and trust everyone you live with and a door accidentally gets locked with no one inside the room, but if you have a slightly suspect house mate, round knobs with a security lock have an advantage.

For example, back when I was in college, many students found that they could easily use a clothes hanger to enter their own or someone else's locked dorm room using a clothes hanger underneath the door from the outside to pull down on the newly installed lever-style handles facing the interior of the room. The college replaced all the knobs on the interior side of the dorm rooms as a result.

Comment: This is entirely a question of lever design. My cat is living proof - she could open the doors in the old place by jumping and holding on to the lever. In the new home, she tried a couple times, then gave up. Rounded levers where cats (and cloth hangers) slip off.

Comment: The root problem here is that the internal lever fully unlocks the door.  If it were designed such that there were a separate deadbolt, or even that the "twist-lock" button on the lever had to be operated independent of the lever itself, this wouldn't be a problem.  (I have seen both knob- and lever- sets where neither internal nor external handle will move until the center button is moved to the unlock position)

Comment: Note that over here (Europe/Germany) lever type with security lock are perfectly normal. The lever goes to a spring bolt and the key to a separate dead bolt. You basically choose between cassettes for ward or double cylinder/security lock (depending on trust/required security level). There's also a restroom variety where instead of a key the inside has a knob (which for safety reasons that can usually be operated by a coin or a generic tool from the outside)

Comment: Adding a thumb-turn isn't going to improve security significantly as there are tools which can be used to bypass those too. The root problem *is* the lever. A doorknob requires actual grip to turn, a thumbturn doesn't, nor does a lever. Here's an excellent talk discussing this kind of issue: https://youtu.be/4YYvBLAF4T8?t=15m37s

Comment: Afterthought to comment above: I've never seen a cassette over here without separate dead bolt. For student dorm rooms (or separate flats inside a house), the choice here would be for the outside lever vs. fixed knob (i.e. doesn't operate spring bolt) vs. knob turning the spring bolt (for free choice of function by inhabitant while  maintaining common look&feel) on the outside (always lever inside and double-cylinder security lock for dead bolt): that is, choose between risk of locking yourself out accidentally vs. risk of forgetting to lock the door when leaving. Your choice.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: with our European versions, the lever never unlocks the dead bolt. This is sometimes discussed as an issue wrt. fire safety, and there are recommendations not to lock in anyone (including yourself) with the deadbolt.

Comment: @cbeleites  agreed -- just wanted to mention that all sorts of variations exist.  In the US, one can still buy standalone double-key deadbolts (meaning without the key, you can't even unlock from the inside; intended to stop someone from breaking a window and reaching in to open the door)

Comment: Am I the only one puzzled by the coathanger thing? How on earth could you manoeuvre a- presumably a three-foot length of straightened wire coathanger - under a door and grab the handle?

Comment: @peterG and anyone else in disbelief, here is a YouTube video demonstrating the method also at a college: https://youtu.be/LHriyi4ViI4 You will note that I neglected to mention that a piece of string is crucial.

Comment: @statueuphemism Thanks very much for taking the time to answer this and posting that link - it's all clear now!

Answer (score 6):

I've gotten my pocket/belt loops caught in the handle when maneuvering around doors. Have tripped myself/destroyed belt loops this way.

EXAMPLE!

[image]

Comment: 0
down vote
Use a HEWI 111-style door handle instead: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/HEWI - you may call it old-fashioned (it's a design from 1969, almost 50 years old), but OTOH I see you are wearing pants which were designed in 1871...so give it a thought, maybe? ;-)

Comment: @Klaws - Those just look so stupid though. Also, you can have my 501s after you pull them off my cold dead legs.

Comment: @Klaws Thanks for the info, did not know that style had a name. Do you know the proper name of the non HEWI door style? Just in case I'm ever swapping over and I know what to avoid. As for the old fashioned, if something is an efficient solution and is reliable, I don't see a need to change. All I know, is that I have suffered under the oppression of the NON-HEWI lever door handle and would like to point out those injustices. You're right however, I am foolishly charging HEWI'S with actions they never caused. =)

Comment: No, I am not aware of a specific name for the non-HEWI-111-style door handles. The HEWI-111-style is nowadays available from many different manufacturers (and they obviously cannot call them "HEWI" for trademark reasons). I just have such handles on the garden shed (they tend to interfere less not only with *my* "1871 style" pants, but also with hoses and cables and such) and still work well with greasy/oily hands.

Answer (score 4):

One disadvantage of using levers is mentioned in this article in [The Economist](https://www.economist.com/news/americas/21600988-new-building-rules-will-help-old-folkswho-now-risk-being-eaten-bears-knobless-oblige) - they may be more easily opened by bears (and velociraptors).

> True, elderly and disabled people find it easier to operate doors with
>   handles. But so do bears. In British Columbia, bears have been known
>   to scavenge for food inside cars—whose doors have handles, knob
>   advocates point out. Pitkin County, Colorado, in the United States,
>   has banned door levers on buildings for this very reason. One
>   newspaper columnist in the pro-knob camp has noted that the
>   velociraptors in “Jurassic Park” were able to open doors by their
>   handles.

Comment: ...more practically, by dogs. I had a dog that figured out how to open every door in the house by getting on her hind legs and scrabbling at the handle. The most problematic part of that is that, being a dog, she wasn't much for closing said doors, as much as she was for knocking them wide open and leaving them. Particularly awkward with bathroom doors, and any time the room occupants may not have been fully clothed. I've heard tales of cats learning to do this too.

Answer (score 4):

Lever doorknobs are now mandated by the ADA (Velociraptors with Disabilities Act) because they are much easier to operate for people with poor motor skills (or very short arms).  That's why they are practically universal in commercial buildings.

Keep in mind ADA is not a "fist of God" requirement, and the primary doctrine of ADA is "readily achievable", or in new construction "unless impractical", hence the ability of a town to override it for cause of bears.

As far as snagging clothes, that is particularly a problem for firemen due to their gear, and also can snag fire hoses.  As such an enhancement was mandated in public spaces:

[image]

And this is a pretty good idea overall.  This is the only kind I would install.

Answer (score 2):

As [Mazura](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/23295) summarized, "Levers don't have as many aesthetic options as knobs."

My house has four types of door "knobs".  Just looking at the hardware, you can tell how it should be opened.  From most common to least common:

- Small (non-rotating) knobs:  Swing the cabinet door open.
- Large vertical handles:  Slide the pocket door sideways.
- Modest horizontal handles:  Pull the cabinet out.
- Normal (rotating) knobs:  Twist the knob, and swing the door open.

The (few) interior doors that have "normal" (rotating) knobs have glass/"crystal" knobs, because they look nice in our style of house.

I like the contrast between the knobs and the handles; it makes it easy to tell how to operate the door.  Lever-style knobs would not have as much contrast (vs. handles), and are not needed/available for cabinet doors.

Comment: Levers don't have as many aesthetic options as knobs. +1

Answer (score 2):

Our cats can open our doors with levers.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Boy, does this make me glad we have knobs; our youngest cat is far too adventurous as it is...

Comment: My cat can turn knobs. I bet with levers you'd get more scratches on the door. -1 @levers

Comment: All the interior doors in my house have big claw marks on them around the handle because a previous dog of ours figured this out too.

Answer (score 2):

My mother uses a walker and she moved into an apartment complex with some flat, but sharp, lever handles (i.e. not rounded). She kept hitting them and cutting her hand.

I replaced them with some rounded levers. But be aware of those older ones from a time when people were not concerned with sharp edges (not a problem on doorknobs).

Comment: Levers don't feel good, no matter what (and they're noisy). +1